# ES6 object assignment simplification

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-next

I have the following code (is working well)

```
const action = {
  type: types.CHANGE_ADMIN_USER_PASSWORD,
  password: initialState.admin.editUserPassword.password,
  confirm: initialState.admin.editUserPassword.confirmPassword,
  ...input
};
```

where `input` is `{ password: 'hello' }` or `{ confirm: 'world' }`. The value can be different, but only one key is present.

**Question**: is there a way to simplify the code? for example, I would like to have `initialState.admin.editUserPassword` only once. UPD: `initialState.admin.editUserPassword` has more than two properties, so I can't include all that object to `action`.

Comment: `const { password, confirmPassword } = initialState.admin.editUserPassword; conost action = {type: ..., password, confirm: confirmPassword, ...input}`

Comment: Keep in mind that this rest object destructing is not ES6, it is stage 3 proposal. https://developer.mozilla.org/cs/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Comment: Given `...input`, it looks you are using experimental features, not just ES6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way would be [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment):

```
const { password, confirmPassword } = initialState.admin.editUserPassword;

const action = {
  type: types.CHANGE_ADMIN_USER_PASSWORD,
  password,
  confirm: confirmPassword,
  ...input
};
```

If the nested object (`initialState.admin.editUserPassword`) only has those two fields (`password`, `confirmPassword`), and do not rename `confirmPassword` to `confirm` you can even do the following:

```
const action = {
  type: types.CHANGE_ADMIN_USER_PASSWORD,
  ...initialState.admin.editUserPassword,
  ...input
};
```

Comment: unfortunately, that object contains not only those two properties. Thanks!

Comment: @dhilt  Looking at your initial example, are you not wanting `confirmPassword` transforming into `confirm`,.. ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use destruction above this code:

```
const {password, confirmPassword} = initialState.admin.editUserPassword;
const action = {
  type: types.CHANGE_ADMIN_USER_PASSWORD,
  password: password,
  confirm: confirmPassword,
  ...input
}
```

Comment: `password: password` can be shortened to `password`. Check my comment under question

Comment: This will actually speed up your code a bit, because fetching nested object property like `initialState.admin.editUserPassword.password` several times is slower than assigning this value to variable and using it later. And makes code more readable as well.

Comment: Yeah I know that `password` can be shorted, but I personally don't like that kind of syntax. For me it makes code less readable and understandable. Again it is just my opinion.